# Firewall Recommendation GCP

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform

We have hosted our platform on Google Cloud. Its a startup and its pretty lean setup with

1 X Nginx | acting as a web server | Public facing subnet
1 x Database server | internal subnet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhZZh.gif)

I am 100% sure that this is not a recommended practice because in traditional on-premise, we never put our web server public facing and it was always behind our firewalls. But I am puzzled as in what are my options to protect my web server

can anyone please guide me on achieving below

Internet users <------> Firewall (hosted on GCP) <-------> Nginx Web server <------> DB.

As this is a startup without funding, please help me with some low cost / open source options.

Cheers
AJ

Answer (score 0):

By default, your VPC(network) is already protected by the Google Cloud Firewall unless you open more ports than you really need.

To start, there is two [default and implied rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules), the allow egress and deny ingress that can only be overridden but not removed.

The second important characteristic is that the rules are [stateful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall), where the reply to an authorized connection is allowed through the firewall.

Another important factor is the rules are either allow or deny. The rule cannot simply log as an action. Here you can find all the [specifications](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#specifications).

There is a tutorial for firewall rules including some configuration examples in this [page](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)

Thinking about your case, I can suggest something along these lines:

1) WebServer and DB are in the same VPC (Internal Network)

2) Use a firewall rule attached to a tag, as an example: http-server or https-server and allow either or both ports 80 and 443.

3) Set up your database and remove the External IP associated to it to increase protection.

4) Attach a tag to both VMs that only the WebServer can communicate to the Database and vice versa.

5) Thinking ahead (and hoping that your project fly) with a little more investment you can add the benefit of a [HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https) that will provide even more protection (DDOS mitigation as an example) and balance the load to multiple WebServers (providing redundancy and horizontal scaling).